# what's the fastest winforms datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, infragistics

I'm currently using a Infragistic UltraGrid and it struggles to handle 500 cell updates per second i.e. the GUI is jerky and slow.

What's the fastest winforms grid on the market? I need a grid that can handle 1000 cell updates per second on a high-spec quad-core 32-bit xp machine with 4 gb of RAM.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of cell updates do you mean?  Are you updating 1000 bound-values per second, or rebinding to a new DataSource every second?  Is it purely read-only?

Comment: 1000 bound-values per second. The cells get updated. thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem that you are trying to solve? I am puzzled here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the telerik one, or customize the the WPF one. But the real question is if You need 1000 cell updates per second (roughly 100 microseconds update) why do You need to display all updates at once. Human eye is not going to comprehend this anyway (30 updates per second will make You head blow anyway), so why not use a Observer pattern, update the underlying data structure as often as needed and set an update interval of 1/50 of the second which should be enough.

And if YOu are not using it for human communication then maybe a feed will suffice (if other people subscribe to it).

Luke

Answer (score 0):

I think grids are mostly made for allowing you to edit tables of data so there is a lot of overhead in showing editors, firing events, bindings, etc.  Perhaps you could create a panel and override the paint event to display your data.  If that isn't fast enough, you could create a XNA/SlimDX/DirectX control that renders your data updates on your computer's video hardware.